# terraform lifecycle prevent destroy

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am working with Terraform V11 and AWS provider; I am looking for a way to prevent destroying few resources during the destroy phase. So I used the following approach.

```
lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true

}
```

When I run a "terraform plan" I get the following error.

```
the plan would destroy this resource, but it currently has 
lifecycle.preven_destroy set to true. to avoid this error and continue with the plan. 
    either disable or adjust the scope.
```

All that I am looking for is a way to avoid destroying one of the resources and its dependencies during the destroy command.

Comment: What do you mean by recreating? Do you want to create a new resource with a new name?

Comment: Modified the post to clarify. I want to be able to destroy everything except for one resource with its dependency. from what I have gathered thus far, with prevent_destroy = true I will need to add -target to the destroy command to only destroy the objects I need. I was hoping if there was an option to negate what I don't want to destroy.

Comment: This is very possible, but more information needs to be provided about the use case, plan, and config.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: sorry for my late response. I came to learn that this is added by design as an alert that you'll need to remove manually to destroy this asset. i could be wrong but this is what I think the use of it.

Comment: correct, i learned the same thing. thx for your feedback

Comment: @Moe so what was the resolution? how did you solve your problem? I am in the similar situation, I have to destroy everything but one resource. Using -target as suggested seems to be madness as it is easier to specify what to omit rather than what to delete.

Comment: I didn't play much with it. I guess it's intended to warn before destroying and if you want to destroy that resource you'll have to comment it out after it errors.

Comment: Please post the Terraform code for the `resource`s that you are trying to provision. Some AWS resources require replacement rather than in-place updating.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK This feature is not yet supported
You need to remove that resource from state file and then reimport it

```
terraform plan | grep <resource> | grep id 
terraform state rm <resource>
terraform destroy
terraform import <resource> <ID>
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this would be to comment out all of the the resources that you want to destroy and then do a `terraform apply`.

Comment: Is this actually the best way to do that? That clearly doesn't scale.

Comment: Quite handy, actually

Comment: @BenLongo that is the purpose of using lifecycles. Its recommended to not use lifecycles if you can, because it completely alters the way Terraform behaves.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the most practical way to manage this is through a combination of variables that allow the resource in question to be conditionally created or not on via the use of `count`, alongside having all other resources depend on the associated Data Source instead of the conditionally created resource.

A good example of this is a Route 53 Hosted Zone which can be a pain to destroy and recreate if you manage your domain outside of AWS and need to update your nameservers, waiting for DNS propagation each time you spin it up.

1. By specifying some variable

```
variable "should_create_r53_hosted_zone" {
  type        = bool
  description = "Determines whether or not a new hosted zone should be created on apply."
}
```

2. you can use it alongside `count` on the resource to conditionally create it.

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "new" {
  count = var.should_create_r53_hosted_zone ? 1 : 0
  name  = "my.domain.com"
}
```

3. Then, by following up with a call to the associated Data Source

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "existing" {
  name = "my.domain.com"
  depends_on = [
    aws_route53_zone.new
  ]
}
```

4. you can give all other resources consistent access to the resource's attributes regardless of whether or not your flag has been set.

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "rds_reader_endpoint" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.existing.zone_id
  # ...
}
```

This approach is only slightly better than commenting / uncommenting resources during `apply`, but at least gives some consistent, documented way of working around it.

Comment: But how does this prevent aws_route53_zone.new from being destroyed? If it gets created, it winds up in the state file anyway, right?