# How do I prevent Terraform from destroying the virtual machine after changing keyvault or change of vm credentials?

Tags: terraform, azure-keyvault, azure-virtual-machine, destroy

I'm trying to change the keyvault used by my virtual machine in terraform. When I trying to apply the changes, Terraform then tried to replace the virtual machine with the new key vault. How do I just change the keyvault used by the vm or change the creds in terraform without destroying the virtual machine ?

I tried to use lifecyle (prevent_destroy = true) but it then fails showing this message

`>  Error: Instance cannot be destroyed

> on .terraform\modules\avd_vm\Modules\AVD_VM\main.tf line 388:
> 388: resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "acumen_vm_kv" {
>
> Resource module.avd_vm.azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.acumen_vm_kv has
> lifecycle.prevent_destroy set, but the plan calls for this resource to be
> destroyed. To avoid this error and continue with the plan, either disable
> lifecycle.prevent_destroy or reduce the scope of the plan using the -target
> flag.`

Comment: Does Azure allow an Update in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same from my end.***

Received same error:

```
Resource vmpassword has lifecycle.prevent_destroy set, but the plan calls for this resource to be destroyed. To avoid this error and continue 
│ with the plan, either disable lifecycle.prevent_destroy or reduce the scope of the plan using the -target flag
```

[image]

> Note: ***If you are trying to have  two different Key Vaults for VM,
> it would be better to use another resource block for new keyvault.***

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "vmpassword" {
  name         = "vmpassword"
  value        = random_password.vmpassword.result
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv1.id
  depends_on = [ azurerm_key_vault.kv1 ]


  lifecycle {
            prevent_destroy = true
    }

}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv2" {
  name                        = "kavy-newkv2"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false
  sku_name = "standard"
  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
    key_permissions = [
      "Get","Create", "Decrypt", "Delete", "Encrypt", "Update"
    ]
    secret_permissions = [
      "Get", "Backup", "Delete", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Set",
    ]
    storage_permissions = [
      "Get", "Restore","Set"
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "vmpassword" {
  name         = "vmpassword"
  value        = random_password.vmpassword.result
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv1.id
  depends_on = [ azurerm_key_vault.kv1 ]
}
```

***import each resource manually to show in your state file. Terraform tracks each resource individually.***

[image]

You can ignore changes in vm ,if required

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      
      tags,
    ]
  }
```

[image]

**Reference:**

1. [terraform-lifecycle-prevent-destroy | StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61451870/terraform-lifecycle-prevent-destroy)
2. https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#prevent_destroy