I need to specifically comment out a terraform resource to prevent it from destroying
I want to specifically prevent one resource from destroying. I have added a inline powershell script in template/AnalyzeChanges.yml when additional parameter is set to destroy then the resource commented out through the powershell script should become exceptional from destroying. But when plan-destroy runs it is destroying everything . Can someone suggest me how to achieve this.
azurepipeline.yml
    name: $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(SourceBranchName)_$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)

trigger: none
parameters:
  - name: env
    type: string
    default: dev
    values:
      - dev
      - prod

  - name: regions
    type: string
    default: westeurope
    values:
      - westeurope
  
  - name: action
    type: string
    default: deploy
    values:
      - deploy
      - plan
      - plan-deploy
      - plan-destroy
      - Initialize
      - marketplace-subscribe

variables:
  - template: variables/${{ parameters.env }}/default.yml
  - template: variables/${{ parameters.env }}/${{ parameters.regions }}/default.yml
  - name: additionalTerraformStatements
    ${{ if eq( parameters['action'], 'plan-destroy') }}:
      value: "-destroy"
         
## Stage: Terraform Plan
## Initialize the new setup for any new landing zone
  - stage: Initialize
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.action }}', 'Initialize')
    displayName: 'Terraform Initialize'
    jobs:
    - template: templates/Initialize.yml
      parameters:
        hubSubscription: '$(hubSubscription)'
        agentPool: '$(agentPool)'
        agentImage: '$(agentImage)'
        updateVariablesScript: '$(updateVariablesScript)'
        marketplaceScript: '$(marketplaceScript)'
        parametersFile: '$(parametersFile)'
        parametersPath: '$(parametersPath)/${{ parameters.env }}/${{ parameters.regions }}'
        terraformDirectory: '$(terraformDirectory)'
        marketplacePublisher: '$(marketplacePublisher)'
        marketplaceProduct: '$(marketplaceProduct)'
        location: '$(locatione)'
        fw_size: '$(fw_size)'
        fw_bundle: '$(fw_bundle)'
        panos_version: '$(panos_version)'
        adminuser: '$(adminuser)'
        subscription_id: '$(subscription_id)'
        prefix: '$(prefix)'
        resourceGroupPaloAlto: '$(resourceGroupPaloAlto)'
        resourceGroupStorage: '$(resourceGroupStorage)'
        storageAccount: '$(storageAccount)'
        StorageAccountFileShare: '$(StorageAccountFileShare)'
        StorageAccountFileShareDirectory: '$(StorageAccountFileShareDirectory)'
        blobContainerTerraform: '$(blobContainerTerraform)'
        tfStateFile: '$(tfStateFile)'
        tfplan: '$(tfplan)'
  
#   # execute terraform plan for all 3 modules combined
  - stage: plan
    condition: or(eq('${{ parameters.action }}', 'plan'),eq('${{ parameters.action }}', 'plan-deploy'),eq('${{ parameters.action }}', 'plan-destroy'))
    displayName: 'Terraform Plan'
    jobs:
    - template: templates/AnalyzeChanges.yml
      parameters:
        hubSubscription: '$(hubSubscription)'
        agentPool: '$(agentPool)'
        agentImage: '$(agentImage)'
        updateVariablesScript: '$(updateVariablesScript)'
        marketplaceScript: '$(marketplaceScript)'
        parametersFile: '$(parametersFile)'
        parametersPath: '$(parametersPath)/${{ parameters.env }}/${{ parameters.regions }}'
        terraformDirectory: '$(terraformDirectory)'
        storageAccountKey: '$(storageAccountKey)'
        localAdminSecret: '$(localAdminSecret)'
        artifacts: '$(artifacts)'
        additionalTerraformStatements: '${{variables.additionalTerraformStatements}}'
        terraformvar: '$(terraform-var)'
        location: '$(locatione)'
        fw_size: '$(fw_size)'
        fw_bundle: '$(fw_bundle)'
        panos_version: '$(panos_version)'
        marketplacePublisher: '$(marketplacePublisher)'
        marketplaceProduct: '$(marketplaceProduct)'
        adminuser: '$(adminuser)'
        subscription_id: '$(subscription_id)'
        prefix: '$(prefix)'
        resourceGroupPaloAlto: '$(resourceGroupPaloAlto)'
        resourceGroupStorage: '$(resourceGroupStorage)'
        storageAccount: '$(storageAccount)'
        StorageAccountFileShare: '$(StorageAccountFileShare)'
        StorageAccountFileShareDirectory: '$(StorageAccountFileShareDirectory)'
        blobContainerTerraform: '$(blobContainerTerraform)'
        tfStateFile: '$(tfStateFile)'
        tfplan: '$(tfplan)'
  
#   ## Stage: Terraform Apply
#   # execute terraform apply for all 3 modules combined based on the approval

  - stage: apply
    condition: or(eq('${{ parameters.action }}', 'deploy'),eq('${{ parameters.action }}', 'plan-deploy'),eq('${{ parameters.action }}', 'plan-destroy'))
    displayName: 'Terraform Apply'
    jobs:
    - template: templates/ApplyChanges.yml
      parameters:
        hubSubscription: '$(hubSubscription)'
        agentPool: '$(agentPool)'
        agentImage: '$(agentImage)'
        updateVariablesScript: '$(updateVariablesScript)'
        parametersFile: '$(parametersFile)'
        storageAccountKey: '$(storageAccountKey)'
        artifacts: '$(artifacts)'
        additionalTerraformStatements: '${{variables.additionalTerraformStatements}}'
        location: '$(locatione)'
        fw_size: '$(fw_size)'
        fw_bundle: '$(fw_bundle)'
        panos_version: '$(panos_version)'
        marketplacePublisher: '$(marketplacePublisher)'
        marketplaceProduct: '$(marketplaceProduct)'
        adminuser: '$(adminuser)'
        subscription_id: '$(subscription_id)'
        prefix: '$(prefix)'
        resourceGroupPaloAlto: '$(resourceGroupPaloAlto)'
        resourceGroupStorage: '$(resourceGroupStorage)'
        storageAccount: '$(storageAccount)'
        StorageAccountFileShare: '$(StorageAccountFileShare)'
        StorageAccountFileShareDirectory: '$(StorageAccountFileShareDirectory)'
        blobContainerTerraform: '$(blobContainerTerraform)'
        tfStateFile: '$(tfStateFile)'
        tfplan: '$(tfplan)'

templates folder has analyze.yml,apply.yml.
analyze.yml
## Define parameters for the pipeline

parameters:
  hubSubscription: ''
  agentPool: ''
  agentImage: ''
  updateVariablesScript: ''
  marketplaceScript: ''
  parametersFile: ''
  parametersPath: ''
  terraformDirectory: ''
  storageAccountKey: ''
  localAdminSecret: ''
  artifacts: ''
  additionalTerraformStatements: ''
  terraformvar: ''
  resourceGroupStorage: ''
  storageAccount: ''
  blobContainerTerraform: ''
  location: ''
  fw_size: ''
  fw_bundle: ''
  panos_version: ''
  marketplacePublisher: ''
  marketplaceProduct: ''
  adminuser: ''
  subscription_id: ''
  prefix: ''
  resourceGroupPaloAlto: ''
  StorageAccountFileShare: ''
  StorageAccountFileShareDirectory: ''
  tfStateFile: ''
  tfplan: ''
   
jobs:
- job: tf_plan
  displayName: tf plan
  pool:
    name: '${{ parameters.agentPool }}'
    vmImage: '${{ parameters.agentImage }}'

  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Comment Out Express Route Circuit Resource if Additional Parameter is Set'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $filePath = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/${{ parameters.terraformDirectory }}/expressroute/main.tf"
        Write-Host "File path: $filePath"
        $additionalParameter = "${{ parameters.additionalTerraformStatements }}"
        Write-Host "Additional Parameter: $additionalParameter"
        
        # Check if the file exists
        if (Test-Path $filePath) {
          Write-Host "File exists. Printing initial content:"
          Get-Content $filePath

          if ($additionalParameter -ne "") {
            $lines = Get-Content $filePath
            $inCommentBlock = $false
            $lines | ForEach-Object {
              if ($_ -match "#express route circuit resource starts here") {
                $inCommentBlock = $true
                "# $_"
              } elseif ($_ -match "#express route circuit resource ends here") {
                $inCommentBlock = $false
                "# $_"
              } elseif ($inCommentBlock) {
                "# $_"
              } else {
                $_
              }
            } | Set-Content $filePath

            Write-Host "Updated file content:"
            Get-Content $filePath
          } else {
            Write-Host "Additional parameter is empty, skipping comment out."
          }
        } else {
          Write-Host "File does not exist at the specified path."
        }



  - task: TerraformInstaller@1
    displayName: InstallTerraform
    inputs:
      terraformVersion: latest

  - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
    displayName: Reload module
    inputs:
        provider: 'azurerm'
        command: 'init'
        commandOptions: '-upgrade'
        workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.terraformDirectory }}'
        backendServiceArm: '${{ parameters.hubSubscription }}'
        backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: '$(resourceGroupStorage)'
        backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: '$(storageAccount)'
        backendAzureRmContainerName: '$(blobContainerTerraform)'
        backendAzureRmKey: '$(tfStateFile)'


  - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
    displayName: 'Terraform: Plan'
    inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'plan'
      workingDirectory: '$(terraformDirectory)'
      commandOptions: '-out=$(tfplan) -var adminuserpassword=${{ parameters.localAdminSecret }} -var StorageAccountAccessKey=${{ parameters.storageAccountKey }} -var-file=${{ parameters.terraformvar }} ${{ parameters.additionalTerraformStatements }}'
      environmentServiceNameAzureRM: '${{ parameters.hubSubscription }}'
      backendServiceArm: '${{ parameters.hubSubscription }}'
      backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: '$(resourceGroupStorage)'
      backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: '$(storageAccount)'
      backendAzureRmContainerName: '$(blobContainerTerraform)'
      backendAzureRmKey: '$(tfStateFile)'


  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
     targetType: 'inline'
     script: |
       # Write your PowerShell commands here.
         cd ${{ parameters.terraformDirectory }}
         terraform show $(tfplan) > $(artifacts).txt 
         

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy Files: Terraform'
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '${{ parameters.terraformDirectory }}'
      Contents: |
        **/*
        !backend.tfvars
        !.terraform/**/*
      TargetFolder: 'HubSpoke/PA-Hub/terraform'

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy Files: Parameters'
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '${{ parameters.parametersPath }}'
      Contents: |
        **/*
      TargetFolder: 'HubSpoke/PA-Hub/parameters'

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy Files: Scripts'
    inputs:
      Contents: |
        scripts/**
      TargetFolder: 'HubSpoke/PA-Hub'

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifacts'
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: 'HubSpoke/PA-Hub'
      ArtifactName: '${{ parameters.artifacts }}'

apply.yml
## Define parameters for the pipeline Define parameters for the pipeline

parameters:
  hubSubscription: ''
  agentPool: ''
  agentImage: ''
  parametersFile: ''
  updateVariablesScript: ''
  storageAccountKey: ''
  artifacts: ''
  additionalTerraformStatements: ''
  resourceGroupStorage: ''
  storageAccount: ''
  blobContainerTerraform: ''
  location: ''
  fw_size: ''
  fw_bundle: ''
  panos_version: ''
  marketplacePublisher: ''
  marketplaceProduct: ''
  adminuser: ''
  subscription_id: ''
  prefix: ''
  resourceGroupPaloAlto: ''
  StorageAccountFileShare: ''
  StorageAccountFileShareDirectory: ''
  tfStateFile: ''
  tfplan: ''




 ## Define a deployment job named tf_apply

jobs:
- deployment: tf_apply
  displayName: tf apply
  pool:
   
    ## Specify the agent pool and VM image

    name: ${{ parameters.agentPool }}
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.agentImage }}
  environment: 'azure-hub-dev-environement'
   
   ## Specify the deployment strategy to run once

  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:

        ## Download Functions Artifact

        - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
          inputs:
            buildType: 'current'
            artifactName: '${{ parameters.artifacts }}'
            downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)' 
        
        ## Write Variables

       # - task: PowerShell@2
          #displayName: 'Update Variables'
          #inputs:
           # targetType: filePath
           # filePath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/${{ parameters.artifacts }}/${{ parameters.updateVariablesScript }}'
           # arguments: '-parameterFiles "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/${{ parameters.artifacts }}/parameters/${{ parameters.parametersFile }}"'

        - task: TerraformInstaller@1
          displayName: InstallTerraform
          inputs:
            terraformVersion: latest
            
        - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
          displayName: Reload module
          inputs:
            provider: 'azurerm'
            command: 'init'
            commandOptions: '-upgrade'
            workingDirectory: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/${{ parameters.artifacts }}/terraform'
            backendServiceArm: '${{ parameters.hubSubscription }}'
            backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: '$(resourceGroupStorage)'
            backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: '$(storageAccount)'
            backendAzureRmContainerName: '$(blobContainerTerraform)'
            backendAzureRmKey: '$(tfStateFile)'
  
        - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-release-task.TerraformTaskV1@0
          displayName: 'Terraform: Apply'
          inputs:
            workingDirectory: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/${{ parameters.artifacts }}/terraform'
            command: 'apply'
            commandOptions: '${{ parameters.additionalTerraformStatements }} -auto-approve -input=false $(tfplan)'
            environmentServiceNameAzureRM: '${{ parameters.hubSubscription }}'
            backendServiceArm: '${{ parameters.hubSubscription }}'
            backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: '$(resourceGroupStorage)'
            backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: '$(storageAccount)'
            backendAzureRmContainerName: '$(blobContainerTerraform)'
            backendAzureRmKey: '$(tfStateFile)'
  
   


Checkout lifecycle block with the prevent_destroy attribute. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61451870/terraform-lifecycle-prevent-destroy

I don't see what this question has to do wit Azure Pipelines other than you included a lot of pipeline YAML that's irrelevant to your Terraform issue.

@Arko, we don't want to use prevent_destroy attribute as it throws an error .

@DanielMann, we don't want to use prevent_destroy attribute. So other option we could use to comment out the resource to avoid destroying it . So we don't want to manually do it rather we want to automate it using a inline script within pipeline during analyze stage when the parameter additionalterraformstatement is set to destroy .

To stop destroying a resource without using prevent_destroy, you should either use a PowerShell script to comment out the resource in the Terraform configuration during plan-destroy or exclude it by using the -target=!resource_name option dynamically in your pipeline and other approach we can say is to remove the resource from Terraform state using terraform state rm @Deepika

@VinayB - I have used the power shell script within the analyze.yml file . It is commenting out the resource. But when I run plan- destroy , all resources including the commented part is getting destroyed .

Issue might be because Terraform still tracks it in the state file. After commenting it out in your analyze.yml Try to remove it from the Terraform state using the terraform state rm <resource_address> command before running terraform plan-destroy @Deepika
